# Does power only apply to the present and future?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference, word-difference, nouns

Does power only apply to the present and future?

What is different about this noun(power), why don't other nouns act this way? For example: (not real person) Frank was a billionaire and mayor 5 years ago.  However 4 years ago, his wealth plummeted due to bad investments, and he is no longer mayor.  In fact Frank is now living on the streets homeless.  One might say, "He is successful.  He used to be a billionaire and mayor.  Its weird seeing him homeless."  But they wouldn't say, "He is powerful.  He used to be a billionaire and mayor.  Its weird seeing him homeless."

Comment: We don't even say "He has lots of success". We say "he is successful", and after his tumble, that would be "he was successful".

Comment: @WeatherVane I slightly edited the examples, would they be acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the edit relates to my first comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed "He has lots of success" to "He is successful"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @WeatherVane Would "He is successful" be acceptable grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would normally say that "Frank was successful", and "Frank was powerful".  Tense is an aspect of English verbs, not nouns. There is no difference between "successful" and "powerful" here.

One might rhetorically say "Frank is successful", perhaps to imply that he has made a success of living rough, or to say that "success is not about money." However, this is a deliberately surprising use of the word "successful".

Comment: If I said "Frank always works to get success," would success refer to any time period (past, present, and future)

Comment: @user58712  I'm curious, what is your native language?  As James K said, in English nouns have no tense.  Only verbs have tense.  There are only a very few languages where nouns have tense, but perhaps yours is one?

Comment: @Andrew English.  The reason I ask is because power is innately attributed to time.  Without time, power cannot exist.  I had an error of reasoning in other words, I thought that this must mean that power has a tense unlike every other noun, since it is dependent on it.  For example: one can own an apple without time, but one cannot make a decision without time.  I would delete this post if I could.

Comment: @user58712, many nouns have meanings that are time-bound. "Meeting", "Happy", "Anniversary", are three which are all time-bound, but in different ways.

Comment: @ColinFine  How are any of those time-bound?  If I freeze time, those things can still exist.  But power can't exist, as power is the ability to change, and time is the dimension of change.

Comment: @user58712: I don't agree with you. Power exists in a frozen moment of time as much as any other quality does.

Comment: I think this question is starting to become one about philosophy, not the English language.  *From a strictly linguistic perspective*, power is not "innately attributed to time".  Linguistically, "power" works no differently from any other noun.